# Having Pivot item as a directory in isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want each pivot item to be one directory in isolated storage then load every file name into a listbox I find it quite confusing  , can you guys help me with it?

Currently its all just showing in one pivot & for my app, user can actually create a pivot aka directory.

will it be possible to create a code in a way where i can i will load the directory based on the pivotitem name then load all item from that directory?

Thanks >.<

```
public partial class View2 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public String selected;

        public View2()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            LoadFromLocalStorage();

        }



        private void LoadFromLocalStorage()
        {
            try
                {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {

                    //string[] fileNames = store.GetFileNames();

                    string[] fileNames = store.GetFileNames("./general/*.*");
                    var files = new ObservableCollection<string>();


                    foreach (string s in fileNames)
                    {
                        files.Add(s);
                    }
                    lbFiles.ItemsSource = files;
                }
            }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Capture an image first!");

                }

        }



        private static string _first;

        public string First
        {
            get
            {
                return _first;
            }
        }

        private void lbFiles_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            selected = lbFiles.SelectedItem.ToString();
            general item = new general();
            item.viewimage(selected);
            MessageBox.Show(selected);
            _first = selected;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }





    }
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do you expect us to write the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating one pivot item for each directory, its better if you can create a class for the same, name say **"DirectoyItem"** which has the name and a collection of file's(call it as **Files**) name in that directory.

1. For better modularity and clarity create a Viewmodel for the page which has the **Collection( ObservableColelction is most preferred) of "DirectoryItem".** call this collection as **Directories**

   public class ViewModel
   {
       ObservableCollection Directories = new ObservableColelction();

   ```
   // call LoadFromLocalStorage() and add items to this Directories  list
   ```

   }

   public class DirectoryItem:INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       string _name;

   ```
   ObservableCollection<string> Files;

   public DirectoryItem()
   {
       _name = null;
       Files = new ObservableCollection<string>();
   }

   //write public set and get for Name field.

   //notify whenever property changes
   ```

   }
2. Bind this collection items to the PivotControl items. 
   you can do so , as follows

set the datacontext something like this in page constructor

```
public MyPage()
{
    //Initializa components
    this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

1. Finally on application launch, for each directory of the IsolatedStorage create a **DirectoryItem** and store in the Collection of DirectoryItems(**Files**).

By doing this you will create a page which has the pivot controls whose items are the directories of the Isolated storage and each pivot item has the names of the files in that particular directory.